# ListView with databindings view tag isn't correct on view:null

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a simple Adapter but always get the same error

> view tag isn't correct on view:null

On my Activity I'm initializing the adapter as follows:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
OptionsAdapter adapter = new OptionsAdapter(Option.defaultOptions());
binding.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here's my adapter

```
public class OptionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ObservableArrayList<Option> list;

    public OptionsAdapter(ObservableArrayList<Option> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Option getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemBinding binding;

        if (convertView == null) {
            binding =  DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.item_layout, null, false);
            convertView = binding.getRoot();
            convertView.setTag(binding);
        } else {
            binding = (ItemBinding) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

### Update

### R.layout.activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.bixlabs.takeachanceapp.MainActivity">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/background_profile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#f7f8f9"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_top"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="204dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/circle_container"
            android:layout_width="119dp"
            android:layout_height="119dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="60dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/greeting_text"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder_profile" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/greeting_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:textColor="#4a90e2"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_top"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circle_container"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            tools:text="Welcome Bob Forest!" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_date_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/background_profile"
            tools:text="November 22, 2016" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_date_text"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_main_options" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### R.layout.item_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="option"
            type="com.rkmax.model.Option" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@{option.title}"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_number_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{option.account}"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@{option.detail}"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balance_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{option.balanceString}"
            android:textColor="#4eaef7"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detail_text" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: In `DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.item_layout, null, false);` could you try to replace `null` with `parent`?

Comment: It doesn't matter ... It just matter when you look at the efficiency(the view size can be known earlier) ... passing null as parent will not cause this problem

Comment: Also not working with null as parent

Comment: You should use parent instead null but using null is not causing this error